# How to color the area of a tableviewcell behind the index bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

in one of my apps I am using alternating colors for my tableviewcells. The tableview features an indexbar to allow for fast scrolling.

However now my cells are being "cut off" - the area behind the index bar is not colored, although the header is visible behind the index letters. So I figure this is not a problem of the index bar not being transparent, but more of the tableviewcells being too short or something like that.

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

Obviosly the green tableviewcells should reach beneath the index bar and fill the gap.
I've tried coloring the tableviewcells by setting the backgroundcolor of both the cells contentview and backgroundview. The textlabel and accessoryview have both clearcolor set as their background color (and are not opaque).

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

The separators are set to white, that's why they are invisible behind the index bar. If I set them to another color they are visible behind the index bar just like the header is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```

From what I remember it does not work to just set the cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor...

-Michael